# How do you query entries by field value for multi-select field type?

Tags: craft3, custom-fieldtype, elementquery

I am looking to query entries by a field value. The value will be a dynamic variable but i cannot get any results showing with hardcoded state. This is the code i have so far:

```
   $entries = Entry::find()
  ->section('locations')
  //->locationStates('missouri')
  ->orderBy('title asc')
  ->where(['field_locationStates' => 'missuori'])
  ->all();
```

I have looked at the other relevant answers and at the element query docs but i am getting nothing returning when i search with the field-type. I have also tried looping through the entries and accessing the fields like so `$locationEntry->locationStates`. Is it because the field-type is a multi-select that its causing some issues? 
Thanks in advance!